# Adding a section on the bottom of a master page for javascript, if present

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want all my javascript to be on the bottom of a page, so in my Master layout I want:

```
header
body
footer
javascript
```

So my my view pages that use this Master page, I want to be able to write javascript and have it injected in the javascript section in the master page.

How can I do this?  This is basically a Section that is used if the view page needs it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set up an optional section in your master layout:

```
@RenderSection("javascript", required: false)
```

The key part is that second parameter `required` that tells the helper method that it may or may not be present.